# How to fix when using EmailAddress as column name

Tags: laravel-5.8, laradock

I am using the default auth in Laravel 5.8 (using make:auth) but cannot get the Reset Password functionality to work. I have an existing Users  table (yes Uppercase U!) which has EmailAddress as the username column name and I suspect this is part of the problem. How may I fix this?

I have modified the Users model and ForgotPasswordController as follows:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    // use Notifiable, HasRoles, UsesUuid; // Traits
    use Notifiable, UsesUuid;

    protected $table = 'Users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
    protected $username = 'EmailAddress';
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getEmailAttribute() 
    {
        return $this->attributes['EmailAddress'];
    }
}
```

```php
class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    protected $username = 'EmailAddress';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'EmailAddress';
    }

    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['EmailAddress' => 'required|email']);
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('EmailAddress');
    }

    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return back()
                ->withInput($request->only('EmailAddress'))
                ->withErrors(['EmailAddress' => trans($response)]);
    }
}
```

I expect to receive an email with the reset link but this never gets sent. The /password/reset page does not redirect, just reloads.

Comment: What mail driver are you using for the emails? Do other emails from you app get sent out fine? I can see that you've added an `email` accessor to your model -- does this definitely return the users email address?

Comment: I am usiong the log driver with Telescope.

Comment: I am using the log driver with Telescope and other emails are getting sent from the app, e.g, register account. I re-did artisan make:auth and I am now getting the reset password email. However when I click the verify button in the email this does nothing.

Comment: It does nothing at all?? Does it 404? Have you checked the error logs to see if there is an issue? Have you set the `APP_URL` in your `.env` file?

Comment: It just does a page refresh. There is nothing in the error logs. I tried setting the APP_URL from localhost to a custom url and this broke the system so I changed it back.

Comment: btw, the system was setup with Laradock.